# WorkManager doesn't start after reboot on real device

Tags: java, android

I want my app to display a notification after reboot. Everything works when I try it on emulator but it doesn't work on real device. (Huawei p20 pro). There is no action when the system boots.
Turns out Huawei has this thing called automatic management which when I turned off made the app worked as intended.

However there are some apps installed on the device that have it turned on and somehow bypass this setting, any idea how is this achieved?

Do other brands have something similar? If yes, how to bypass those?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Here is my code for

**OnRebootReceiver.java**

```
public class OnRebootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //DB
    private ReminderService reminderService;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.reminderService = new ReminderService(context);

        reminderService.setReminder();
    }
}
```

note : method `setReminder()` doesn't set any background/foreground service nor have I asked any permission in that regard. It schedules new work using workManager. Not sure if that matters

**Manifest**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  .
  .
  <receiver android:name=".Adapters.Reminder.OnRebootReceiver"
       android:exported="true">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
       </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```